# Django admin filter urls for not-equals

Tags: django, django-admin, django-modeltranslation

I've created a custom `FieldListFilter` for my site's admin for whether `modeltranslation` translations are available for a field.

It creates a filter that currently looks like this on the sidebar:

[image]

The "Lacks English" option adds `vt_title_en__exact=` to the query string.

I would like to also implement a "Has English" which does the opposite filter. Can I do that with a django admin site url query strings?

Btw: source for my custom filter: https://github.com/yairchu/azlemi/blob/master/vote/admin.py#L30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `vt_title_en__gt=` can do the job.  Any non-empty string is greater than "".

Comment: Nice! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create `queryset` method for do it, because there is no such possibility to put exclusion or negation into `expected_parameters`.